# EJS tag on external javascript file

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I have a nodejs app where I'm using EJS as a templating engine.

My question is : **Is there a solution to use EJS tags eg:`<%=data.name%>` on external javascript files?**

I've added the directory that contains the javascript files to the `Express JS` status folders like so :

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/documents'));
```

But I can't use EJS tags`<%%>`on external js files located in the `/documents` directory.

Comment: You can only use the ejs syntax on ejs files, they wont work in js files.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to do this by assigning variables outside of the external javascript file.

```
<script>var x = <%-JSON.stringify(y)%></script>
<script src="/js/myJS.js" type="text/javascript"><script>
```